# Formally proving $\lim_{x\to 1}(x^2+1)=2$

Tags: calculus, limits

I know this is a really basic question, but I just can't do this limit even while looking at other examples...

> I need to prove that $\lim\limits_{x\to 1}(x^2+1)=2$, using delta and epsilon.

I just can't 'formally' demonstrate this, please help.

For me its just obvious that $x^2$ with $x\to1$ should be $1$, and I understand that epsilon is the difference between points near $x=1$, and delta is how 'near' those f(x's) is to f(x=1). Yet I don't know how to use both of them to reach a proof that $x^2 + 1 = 2$.

edit: How far I got -
$0<|(x^2 + 1)-2|<\epsilon$ ergo $|x-1|<\frac{\epsilon}{|x+1|}$. Let $ \delta = 1$:

$-1 < \epsilon < 1$ so $1<x+1<3$, then : $\frac{\epsilon}{3}<\frac{\epsilon}{x+1}< \epsilon$

This what I worked to discover, now the proof:

$\forall \epsilon>0 \exists \delta>0$:

$0<|x-1|<\delta$ and $|(x^2+1)-2|<\epsilon$, $\delta = min(1, \epsilon)$

Now what?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for.

Comment: Also, don't get discouraged by the downvote. I downvoted the question and voted to close it because at the moment, it is not up to site standards (you have shown no work you did on your own). If you edit your question so that you show what you tried and how far you got, I will not only remove the downvote, I will add an upvote. Even if the question is closed, you can still edit it, and we will vote to reopen it.

Comment: Also, a very basic hint: write down the definitions, and write down what you want to prove. That would be the bare minimum of "showing your own work".

Comment: [Here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a MathJax tutorial for formatting math here.

Comment: Thanks StubbornAtom!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $|x -1| <1$;

Then $0<x<2$, and $1<x+1<3$;

Let $\epsilon$ be given

Choose $\delta =\min (1, \epsilon/3).$

Then

$|x-1|<\delta$ implies

$|x^2-1|=$

$|x-1||x+1|<3|x-1|<3\delta\le \epsilon$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\varepsilon$ be an arbitrary positive number. If $\left| {x - 1} \right| \le \delta : = \sqrt {\varepsilon  + 1}  - 1$, then
$$
\left| {(x^2  + 1) - 2} \right| = \left| {x^2  - 1} \right| = \left| {x + 1} \right|\left| {x - 1} \right| \le \left| {x - 1} \right|^2  + 2\left| {x - 1} \right| \le \varepsilon .
$$

Comment: Could you explain the second to last inequality? It's clear that some trick is needed to get rid of the dependence on $x$, but I can't figure out how you did it.

Comment: @JohnP. $ |x^2-1| = |x^2+2x-2x-2+1| = |(x-1)^2+2(x-1)| \leq |(x-1)^2|+2|(x-1)| $

Comment: Thank you. Very helpful.

Comment: I used $\left| {x + 1} \right|\left| {x - 1} \right| = \left| {x - 1 + 2} \right|\left| {x - 1} \right| \le (\left| {x - 1} \right| + 2)\left| {x - 1} \right| = \left| {x - 1} \right|^2  + 2\left| {x - 1} \right|.$

Comment: I'm sorry for all the questions. The only inequality I'm having difficulty understanding is $|x-1 + 2| \leq (|x-1|  + 2)$. Could you explain where this?

Comment: Oh, it is the triangle inequality, right?

Comment: Yes, it is by the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

The steps to solving your problem are as follows:

1. Write down the definition of the statement $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$.
2. Replace $a, f$ and $L$ in that definition with the actual values you have in your particular problem (in other words, write down the actual statement you need to prove).
3. You should now have some sort of statement of the form $\forall \epsilon > 0\exists \delta > 0 \forall x: A\implies B$, where $A$ and $B$ are statements including $x, \epsilon$ and $\delta$.
4. Think about the relation $A$, and how it is connected to $B$.

If you still have problems, write (in an edit to your question) how far along the 4 steps you got and where you are now stuck, and we can help you further.